# Posicionamento da terceira div

Tags: html

Tenho 3 divs e a ideia é que as primeiras duas uma ao lado da outra, então usei o `float: left`:

```
<div class="div1" id="employee_table" style="float: left;">

</div>  

<div class="div2" id="employee_table" style="float: left;">

</div>
```

Mas agora tenho uma terceira `div` e pretendo que fique por baixo da segunda `div`, como posso fazer?

Mostro na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como assim por baixo? totalmente encoberta pela segunda? Tem uma imagem do layout que pretende fazer?

Comment: @hugocsl editei a pergunta com uma imagem do que pretendo

Comment: Tem que ser com Float mesmo ou pode ser outra coisa tipo flex ou grid?

Comment: @hugocsl pode ser do tipo flex ou grid

Comment: Vou ver se faço uma opção em flex pra te ajudar tb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue um modelo com `float` como vc queria, o problema é que com `float` a altura do box da esquerda não fica igual a altura dos boxes da direita, se vc quiser ajustar isso tem que por um valor mão. Além disso, vc precisa fazer um `clearfix`, para o texto que vem depois do `container` não encavalar com os box de cima...

Segue um exemplo básico.

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

.box {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: calc(50% - 20px);
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}
.box.n2,
.box.n3 {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box n1">n1</div>
    <div class="box n2">n2</div>
    <div class="box n3">n3</div>
</div>
    
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae, quam soluta necessitatibus sapiente error laudantium illum, fuga veritatis veniam quibusdam obcaecati voluptatem in aspernatur eum sequi! Ducimus mollitia eos excepturi.
    </p>
<div class="container">
    <div class="box n1" style="height: 60px;">n1</div>
    <div class="box n2">n2</div>
    <div class="box n3">n3</div>
</div>
```

---

Agora uma opção com `Flex` caso te interesse. Aqui os filhos vão acompanhar a altura do irmão ao lado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
article {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50%;
}
article.coluna {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.box {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box.n2,
.box.n3 {
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <article>
        <div class="box n1">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores ea debitis cum illum perferendis labore voluptates at magni omnis unde?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos, nesciunt. Recusandae rerum tempora reprehenderit officia odit! Alias ipsam voluptates veniam officiis laboriosam et odit, ullam molestiae nihil, officia consequatur. </div>
    </article>
    <article class="coluna">
        <div class="box n2">n2</div>
        <div class="box n3">n3</div>
    </article>
</div>
    
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae, quam soluta necessitatibus sapiente error laudantium illum, fuga veritatis veniam quibusdam obcaecati voluptatem in aspernatur eum sequi! Ducimus mollitia eos excepturi.
</p>
```

Comment: Posso tirar só uma dúvida? Ao usar o `float` não posso aumentar o `width` das `divs`? Se aumentar elas já não ficam como pretendo

Comment: @Iniciante o que acontece é que eu dividi cada lado com 50%, então se vc aumentar um lado para 70% o outro vc tem que colocar 30%, o importante é que a soma dos 2 lados tenha 100%, não importa se um lado tem 90% e outro tenha 10%... Esse `calc(50% - 20px);` é pq o 20px é o desconto da margem, que no caso é 10px na direita e 10px na esquerda, então tenho que abater 20px dos 50% que é a largura, ou dos 30%, ou dos 10% e por ai vai, depende da largura que vc definir

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação

Answer (score 2):

Ao usar `float: left` tudo será agrupado à direita dos elementos. Uma forma é inserir uma div com `clear: both;` após a terceira div, evitando que elementos posteriores sejam agrupados à direita das divs:

> Uma observação: não repita id's. Um id deve ser único. No exemplo
>   abaixo converto o id repetido `employee_table` em classe.

Como o @Hugocsl colocou, use `calc` para definir a largura das divs (descontando as margens). Porém a minha sugestão não necessita de divs `container`, como ele colocou.

Veja como fica:

```css
.employee_table{
   float: left;
   margin: 5px;
}

.div1{
   width: calc(40% - 10px);
   background: red;
}

.div2, .div3{
   width: calc(60% - 10px);
}

.div2{
   background: blue;
}

.div3{
   background: yellow;
}

.breaker{
   clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1 employee_table">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>

<div class="div2 employee_table">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
</div>

<div class="div3 employee_table">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
</div>
<div class="breaker"></div>
<p>
   parágrafo
</p>
```

Comment: Obrigado por me lembrar dos id repetidos nas 3 tabelas

Comment: precisava de tirar uma dúvida contigo sobre URL, mas não tem nada a ver com esta pergunta, podes falar no chat?

Comment: @Iniciante sim, manda aí

Comment: @Iniciante Eu tb não sei como fazer. Abre um chat e manda o link.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90814/room-for-iniciante-and-sam

Comment: não tem forma de limpar a URL sem fazer refresh à página?